# Can we stop animation while scrolling back to top in animate.css library

Tags: css, reactjs, animate.css

I am using the **react-animate-on-scroll** package based on the **animate.css** library for animating my text in web page. But I only want the animation to happen while scrolling down and not scrolling up. How can we restrict that?

```
 <ScrollAnimation animateIn='fadeInUp' duration={0.7}>
     <h1 className='mb-4'>Text with animation</h1>
 </ScrollAnimation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, `react-animate-on-scroll` doesn't directly provide the feature to adjust animation based on scrolling direction, unless this feature gets added, another method would be to use state variables and event listeners for scroll.

In NPM, Node.js, utilize `window.pageYOffset` and calculate `scrollDirection` as up or down based on the logic

> 'if the currentScrollPos is greater than the windows vertical scroll
> position'

or in code

```
currentScrollPos > (window.scrollY || window.scrollTop) ? 'down' : 'up'
```

The component can make use of the useEffect hook for adding and removing the event listener. `window.scrollY` is supported in most browsers. It represents the number of pixels that the document is currently scrolled vertically from the top. `window.scrollTop` is a safety check and for older browsers

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ScrollAnimation from 'react-animate-on-scroll';

function MyComponent() {
  const [scrollDirection, setScrollDirection] = useState('down');

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      const scrollDirection = currentScrollPos > (window.scrollY || window.scrollTop) ? 'down' : 'up';
      setScrollDirection(scrollDirection);
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollAnimation animateIn={scrollDirection === 'down' ? 'fadeInUp' : ''} duration={0.7}>
      <h1 className='mb-4'>Text with animation</h1>
    </ScrollAnimation>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: I tried this,  window.scrollTop -> is coming as undefined and scrollY is always as as pageYOffset. That's why the scrollDirection is always coming as Up.

Comment: If window.scrollTop is undefined, maybe using document.documentElement.scrollTop instead of window.scrollY. Let me know. If that doesn't fix it, my other possible solution would be to ensure the scroll event is firing as expected, providing the scroll animation with accurate data, not being delayed or race condition issues.